# Django ORM - confusion about Router.allow_relation()

Tags: python, django, database

In the documentation of the new version of Django there is an ambiguity between what is said in the text and the code shown.

In the section that describes the multidatabase configuration it speaks about the router configuration, and there is a method:

> `allow_relation(obj1, obj2, **hints)`
>
> Return True if a relation between obj1 and obj2 should be allowed, False if the relation should be prevented, or None if the router has
>   no opinion. This is purely a validation operation, used by foreign key
>   and many to many operations to determine if a relation should be
>   allowed between two objects.

At the end of the documentation there is this:

> Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or
>   many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases. If you have
>   used a router to partition models to different databases, any foreign
>   key and many-to-many relationships defined by those models must be
>   internal to a single database.
>
> This is because of referential integrity. In order to maintain a
>   relationship between two objects, Django needs to know that the
>   primary key of the related object is valid. If the primary key is
>   stored on a separate database, it’s not possible to easily evaluate
>   the validity of a primary key.

But the router code given as an example is the following:

```
def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
     """
     Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
     in the primary/replica pool.
     """
     db_list = ('primary', 'replica1', 'replica2')
     if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
         return True
     return None
```

So even if the objects are from different databases the relation is allowed by the software.

Does anyone know what it means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's a good question, and I agree that the multiple-database docs are not as clear as they could be.

The thing to keep in mind is that there are basically two use cases for multi-DB: putting different data (models) on different databases; and setting up a primary / replica DB structure. These use cases are both represented in the primary example in the documentation.

In the different-data scenario, you definitely want `allow_relation()` to reject any relations between two different databases since there's no way to enforce constraints across databases. But in the primary-replica scenario, you have the same data on all the databases, so it's OK to allow relations between any of them.

So if you get one model instance from `replica1` and another from `replica2` (due to the random choice of database for reads), it would be OK to allow a relation between them since the same data exists on `primary`, and that's where the new model data will be written.

Comment: I am still not fully getting the point so i'll accept your answer later but it's helpful.. (i mean i don't get what is the point to allow a relation between databases if the data in it is the same. Are you allowing one copy to be linked to the copy of itself??? Just wondering)

Comment: @softwareplay: The *relation* here refers to, for example, a `ForeignKey` from one model instance to another (say an `Article` instance referencing an `Author` instance). If those tables are kept in different databases then you can't allow the `ForeignKey` since there's no way to enforce its constraints across different databases. But in the primary / replica scenario both tables are represented in the same database, it's just that you might have fetched the two instances from different replicas. In that case it's fine to allow the relation, since all the data will be written to the primary.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, thank you for the answer and explanation. This part is not clearly covered in the Django documentation. Is it safe to allow this when there might be a delay/lag in replication?

Comment: @RajkumarR: It's as safe as using primary/replica at all. Put differently, if you're not willing to read and write to different databases, and there's only one writeable database, then the replicas will never be used.